# Why doesn't left:0 work here?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I was trying to make a sticky div inside the body, that has `css` like:

```
.call-us-alert {
    background-color: #FFB100;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 31px;
    width: 19%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left:-107px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

It works fine on my screen but on a device with a smaller screen, the sticky div vanishes. I know the reason. I have given `margin-left` as `-107px`. But when I try `left:0`, it doesn't work. The div stays where it stays. What is the method to fix it?

Comment: remove margin-left and use `left: -9%;` instead

Comment: I would not be using margin-left at all. Use left: -107px, anyway your element is already fixed. Also it would be nice to see the result you want to achieve on a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove margin-left and use left: -9%; instead

```css
.call-us-alert {
    background-color: #FFB100;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 31px;
    width: 19%;
    top: 50%;
    left: -9%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="call-us-alert"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this code with your original code...

```
.call-us-alert {
    background-color: #FFB100;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 31px;
    width: 19%;
    top: 50%;
    left:0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

hope it will help...